# Proof that open set of a variety has the same dimension

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I have been trying to understand this proof:
[image]

So the first part I am unsure of for the proof of the first inequality: is it possible that when we take the closure of $U_i$ that two of the $X_i$ are actually equal?

Now

2. For the second highlighted part, is it possible that some of the intersection $X_i \cap U$ is empty?
3. And I guess this one will be ansewerd by the previous question, but why is $
   \left(X_{i+1} \cap(X \backslash U)\right)
   $ non empty?

Comment: The linked duplicate shows that for an irreducible set $X$ and nonempty open subset $U\subset X$ that there is a bijection between irreducible closed subsets of $X$ meeting $U$ and irreducible closed subsets of $U$ given by intersecting with $U$ or taking the closure in $X$. The answer there explicitly addresses your "the first part I am unsure..." concerns; $X_i\cap U$ cannot be empty as $U_i=X_i\cap U$ and $U_i$ is nonempty. You may find that other questions of yours are already answered here on MSE - I would recommend doing some searching before asking in the future.